# Python: How to create histogram from binning and frequency table

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, statistics, histogram

Is there an appropriate way of drawing histogram from a binning and frequencies table?

```
import pandas as pd
freq=[3,14,21,12,6]
i=pd.interval_range(start=50,freq=10,end=100,closed='left')
df=pd.DataFrame(index=i,data=freq)
df.columns=['Freq']
df.index.name='Class'
df.columns.name='Column'
print(df)
#??hist(df)
```

Comment: You want a bar plot.

Comment: Get started with [`df.hist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html). Then you can add more features to your chart.

Comment: @JohanC I do want histogram not bar plot

Comment: @CodeDifferent The result from your comment does not work correctly!

Comment: Well, a histogram is just a bar plot with the frequencies.